# Ruby case-when vs JavaScript switch-case

Tags: javascript, ruby

I come from Ruby world and entering the JavaScript world. One feature of Ruby language is the `case` statements to evaluate a target value:

```rb
my_val = case my_var
           when "var1" then "value1"
           when "var2" then "value2"
           else "value3"
         end

# my_val evaluated to a specific value 
puts my_val
```

Can I do something as succinct in JavaScript as above? This is the closest I get:

```js
let myVal = null;
switch (myVar) {
  case "var1": 
    myVal = "value1";
    break;
  case "var2":
    myVal = "value2";
    break;
  default:
    myVal = "value3";
}

// my_val evaluated to a specific value 
console.log(myVal);
```

Comment: _"case statement"_ – it's actually an _expression_.

Comment: Just want to point out it works in Coffeescript just like in Ruby.

Comment: @maxpleaner Yea, I know that too. As coffeescript goes hand in hand with Rails. But it seems coffeescript is not so popular on frontend (React) development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an object with a ternary to set a default value like so:

```js
const obj = {
  "var1":"value1",
  "var2":"value2",
  "defaultVal": "value3" // default value
},
getVal = sVar => sVar in obj ? obj[sVar] : obj["defaultVal"];

// Use case 1:
console.log(getVal("var1")); // get "var1" from the object

// Use case 2:
console.log(getVal("foo")); // get "foo" from the object, doesn't exsist, so we get the default value
```

The above creates an object, where each key in the object points to a value (ie what `myVar` should turn into). If `myVar` is not in the object, it will default to `defaultVal`, if it is in the object it will retrieve the associated value.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) if it just returns value only.

```js
let map = new Map([["var1","value1"], ["var2", "value2"]])
const getVar = myVar => map.has(myVar) ? map.get(myVar) : "value3"

// Use

let myVar = 'var2'
myVar = getVar(myVar)
console.log(myVar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works:

```js
let myVal = null;
let myVar = 'var1';

switch (myVar) {
  case "var1": 
    myVal = "value1";
    break;
  case "var2":
    myVal = "value2";
    break;
  default:
    myVal = "value3";
}

// my_val evaluated to a specific value 
console.log(myVal);
```

But a better way without the `switch` statement:

```js
const obj = {
  var1: 'value1',
  var2: 'value2',
  default: 'value3'
};
const myVar = 'var1';
const myVal1 = obj[myVar] || obj.default;
const myVal2 = obj['asdfasdf'] || obj.default;

console.log(myVal1);
console.log(myVal2);
```

Comment: Just a side note about the second approach: If some of the `var1`, `var2`, ... are defined with a `falsy` value (example `0`) in the object, you will get the default value instead of the defined `falsy` one.

Comment: @Shidersz you right.. I implemented like this because I normally use TypeScript and  as you can see the `var1`, `var2` are `string`s.. But yes, totally agree with you.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can approach something similar using [Boolean Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) `&&` and `||` in `Javascript`:

```js
let my_var = "var2";
let my_val =
(my_var === "var1" && "value1") ||
(my_var === "var2" && "value2") ||
"value3";

console.log(my_val);

let my_var2 = "var3";
let my_val2 =
(my_var2 === "var1" && "value1") ||
(my_var2 === "var2" && "value2") ||
"value3";

console.log(my_val2)
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

**SIDE NOTE:** This approach will only work for primitive `Javascript` values. Lets look to some examples where the approach fails:

```js
let my_var = [1,2,3];
let my_val =
(my_var === "var1" && "value1") ||
(my_var === [1,2,3] && "value2") ||
"value3";

console.log(my_val);

let my_var1 = {"a":"b"};
let my_val1 =
(my_var1 === "var1" && "value1") ||
(my_var1 === {"a":"b"} && "value2") ||
"value3";

console.log(my_val1);

let my_var2 = NaN;
let my_val2 =
(my_var2 === "var1" && "value1") ||
(my_var2 === NaN && "value2") ||
"value3";

console.log(my_val2);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```